# I want to insert a link in an email in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

i want to send a mail to users, the mail is sending , but the link in it is now showing as a link, I also want to embed a logo in the mail but the logo is not showing, below is my code. I am using cake 2.8

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
   $Email->from(array('admin@wacscoac.org'=>'West Africal College of Surgeons'));
   $Email->to($email);
   $Email->subject('Reviewer Invitation From West African College of Surgeons');
   $Email->send('Dear Reviewer, You have been invited by the Head of Faculty  of $faculty from the West'
           . 'African College of Surgeons to register as a reviewer. Please click on the link '
           . 'below to register'
           . 'http://wacscoac.org/edms/users/addreviewer');
   $Email->attachments('img/logo.png');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the logo to be also the link:

I think the best way is to use a template so you can use the Html helper inside your .ctp file

```
$Email->attachments(['img/logo.png'=> [
    'file' => 'img/logo.png',
    'mimetype' => 'image/png',
    'contentId' => 'logo'
]]);
$Email->template('test');
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$Email->viewVars(array(
    'faculty' => "Faculty",
));
$Email->send();
```

Specifying the `contentId` is useful if you want the attachment inline, as explained in the manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments)

After that you have to create a template in `\src\Template\Email\html\test.ctp`

```
<p>Dear Reviewer,</p> 

<p>You have been invited by the Head of Faculty  of <?= $faculty ?> 
from the West African College of Surgeons to register as a reviewer.</p>

<p>Please click on the link below to register</p>

<?= $this->Html->link(
        '<img src="cid:logo" alt="">',         
        'http://wacscoac.org/edms/users/addreviewer', 
        ['escape' => false]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own opinion i would use HTML tags

```
<a href = "site you desire">Link tage</a>
```

But keep in mind that you need to set

`$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";`

for the email , good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = '<a href="http://wacscoac.org/edms/users/addreviewer"'>
             <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>';
```

and then

```
$Email->send('Dear Reviewer, You have been invited by the Head of aculty  of $faculty from the West'  
           . 'African College of Surgeons to register as a reviewer. Please click on the link '
           . 'below to register'
           . $link);
```

Comment: @ AIPD TECH, thanks, but this is the error i got    Error: Call to a member function image() on a non-object

Comment: thanks, but what if the logo.png is in the webroot folder?

Comment: Just remove the `img` from path. I will suggest to use template for sending email. `$Email->emailFormat('html');`